# Writing extensible versus deletable code

Tags: design, programming-practices, code-reuse, extensibility, philosophy

I know this might just be semantics, but reading the article titled [Write code that is easy to delete, not easy to extend](http://programmingisterrible.com/post/139222674273/write-code-that-is-easy-to-delete-not-easy-to) made me think that perhaps it is more or less along the same lines of creating code that is easy to maintain. Now whether it is to make the software easy to update or modify by making it extensible or deletable, it doesn't get away from the principle of good design thinking before coding.

The question I want to ask is, should we be thinking about a style of writing code that is better suited to the contemporary software design and architecture of being agile and user-centric (hence evolving faster compared to business requirements) that incorporates both elements of re-usability and also erasability?

Or perhaps it already exists? Can someone point to some standards or guidelines?

Answer (score 2):

I think layering is undervalued.  I wish there were more texts talking about that as a design point.  Layering means placing an abstraction on top of another abstraction (without allowing the underlying abstraction to leak thru).

One great and highly effective example of layering is when you change languages.  For example, you write some SQL on top of a SQL database, and you get the benefit of millions of lines of code without having to integrate with them at all (for example, you don't have to know what programming language was used to implement SQL)!

DSLs are another great example.  Sometimes creating new source code in a declarative DSL is the best way to isolate one layer from another (the DSL implementing layer).

Our programming languages carry a lot of baggage, for example, doing a new operation usually has language specific requirements that are not your application's requirements (e.g. that a `new String("foo")` should be a separate object from any other object in you application, even other `new String("foo")`'s ).

With appropriate layering we can isolate essential vs. accidental requirements/dependencies/features from each other.

Comment: "We can solve any problem by introducing an extra level of indirection." ("Except for the problem of too many levels of indirection")
[Fundamental theorem of software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering)

Comment: @MiguelvandeLaar, yes, that's true.  However, indirection, and even modularity are more general than layering.  When we laying, each layer stops using the underlying abstractions of the deeper layers further below in favor of only using the new abstractions presented in the immediate layer below.  This forgoing of the other lower abstractions results in superlative loose coupling that enables an architecture keep millions of lines of code more maintainable than if all the code is modular but at the same layer.  It also has the benefit of avoiding circular dependencies, which are notorious.

Comment: I completely agree. My remark was intended to warn for the danger of excessive use of indirection.
Costs for such overuse often include unnecesary overhead and increased complexity

Answer (score 1):

> Should we be thinking about a style of writing code that is better suited to the contemporary software design and architecture of being agile and user-centric (hence evolving faster compared to business requirements) that incorporates both elements of re-usability and also erasability?

The underlying issue with the erasable versus extendable code is understanding. The better the developer(s) understand the problem being solved and how best to solve it, the better the solution can be.

Understanding is not so much a coding style or even a design style - all the elements and techniques discussed in the article (e.g. layering, isolation, composition, common interfaces) are common techniques. It is about a thought process.

The process described in the linked article describes the author's growing understanding. The author starts out copy-pasting code (step 1) then taking a step back and consolidating it into libraries (step 2). Next the author shares common code across projects (step 3) then realizes sharing too much is a maintenance burden and creates isolated abstraction layers (step 4) then repeats with increasingly larger pieces (steps 5, 6 and 7).

While the steps are familiar to developers, the specifics are not that important. They are included for context and to "tell a story". What is important is:

1. Some thinking and design up front is vital but do not stop thinking once you start coding. Unless you are familiar with the problem, your design will change as you learn more.
2. Therefore, do not be afraid to refactor (and deleting code is just a subcategory of refactoring).
3. Therefore, create code that you are comfortable refactoring. If you cannot change the code (e.g. you do not understand it or it is too brittle (e.g. lacks automated tests)), you will be stuck with poor designs.

The author makes a few good side points along the way such as looking for errors and raising them instead of creating cumbersome workarounds.